# Writing an app using more than one language

Tags: c#, java, android, python

I'm currently working on an android app and i'm using Eclipse. I know that Eclipse is used for writing java, but if you were creating an app in many different languages, would you have to write the entire program from scratch for each language? If not what would be the same? Plus, what would be the best program to write it in?

Comment: Probably... Probably not.... depends...  ios vs android yes... android and blackberry no..

Comment: you can take a look at `phonegap` http://phonegap.com/

Comment: @gtgaxiola What do you mean? what languages are mixable and what program would be best to use to write mixed languages in?

Comment: @Aaron check `phonegap`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Language Inseparability** or **Foreign Function Interface**:

These are the key concepts in which languages can
work together with common code bases. Python for example
has many modules that either directly wrap C/C++
libraries or parts of them providing a higher abstraction
layer on top (*In Python*).

If you're going to implement Apps for Android and iOS
and worried about implementation costs; perhaps use
something like [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com), or some other suitable paltform
that helps deal with this such as [Kivy](http://kivy.org/)

**Web Services**:

This is another increasingly common
approach these days. By placing and implement
major parts of your solution as a Web Service
(*aka Cloud*) you can then write thing wrapper/layers
for iOS/Android utilizing your "service" (*assuming
the App stores permit this which I think they do
depending on what your app does*).